# Can one set the initial check state for a MenuItem created with AppendCheckItem in wxPython?

Tags: wxpython

By default, a MenuItem of the check button style is unchecked and for the radio button style the first item in the group is set.

But, can I set such a MenuItem as checked when I create it?  More specifically, can I do so in the statement creating the check item such as in a line like:

```
m_count = self.menu2c.AppendCheckItem(3, "Count")
```

Answer (score 0):

One can do (following the example above)

```
m_count = self.menu2c.AppendCheckItem(3, "Count")
m_count.Check()
```

I suppose that could be the best way, but there feels there should be a one-liner somewhere